# Can you replicate ContentApp functionality in a TaskPaneApp?

Tags: office-js

Is there anyway to create a TaskPaneApp such that when you click on a menu item or button, it opens an iframe in the application similar to what a ContentApp does by default?

I was wondering why I couldn't find the ability to do this until I discovered this functionality lies within the OfficeApp declaration which implies to me this isn't possible. It seems odd to me that this wouldn't be possible though because this functionality would provide so much value to the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not currently supported, but it's a good idea. Please go to [Office Developer User Voice](https://office365.uservoice.com/) and suggest this. (But first search to see if someone else has suggested it and then vote up the suggestion.)

Comment: https://office365.uservoice.com/forums/264636-general/suggestions/19173322-allow-taskpaneapp-to-launch-iframes-like-contentap

Just putting this here incase anyone stumbles across this in the future.